# Are there irregular tilings by L-polyominoes?

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling

I wonder if one can tile the plane with an order-$n$ L-polyomino
in a fundamentally irregular manner.
I seek help in defining what should constitute "irregular."

An [L-polyomino](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L-Polyomino.html) of order $n \ge 2$ is a
line of $n$ unit squares joined edge-to-edge, with one more square attached to the
$n$-th to form an *L*-shape.

I am wondering for which $n$ is there
an order-$n$ L-polyomino that can tile the plane "irregularly."
Two regularities I would like to avoid are:
(1)
within the tiling any rectangle (of any size) tiled by L-polyominoes;
see (a) in the figure below, using order-$4$ polyominoes.
(2)
any "periodic crack," which I define as
an infinite staircase, with a finite periodic series of steps up/down and right/left,
that never includes a point strictly interior to an L-polyomino.
A simple example is in (b) below, but in general steps up and down, right and left,
of varying length, would constitute a periodic crack if
repeated infinitely.
Such a periodic crack partitions the tiling into to "halves";
it is in some sense an infinite "digital line" cleaving the tiling in two halves.

Finally, (c) below shows a partial tiling by order-$4$ polyominoes
which (so far) violates neither (1) nor (2).

[image: Lpoly]

> **Q1**. Is there an irregular tiling by L-polyominoes under my definition of "irregular"?
>
> **Q2**. Are there accepted definitions of what constitutes an irregular tiling,
> by one tile (a [monohedral tiling](http://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/))?

(*Addendum 1*). To respond to Zack's question, let us
insist that the tiles can only be rotated—no mirror reflections permitted.
(This may be not be standard notation...)

(*Addendum 2*). The chair tiling (from [this link](http://black.mitplw.com/tiles/images/symmetry_aperiodic_chair.png)),
as per Anthony Quas, with my superimposed periodic staircase:

[image: Chair+Staircase]

Comment: Do you allow mirror images of the tile?

Comment: Good question, Zack. I was thinking only of congruent copies by 90-degree rotation.

Comment: Of course if $n=2$, you have the `chair tiling'. There are interesting tilings of these. Non-periodic; no subrectangle is covered. I'm not sure if this counts as "regular" or not.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Nice, the "chair tiling" is new to me: ([image link](http://black.mitplw.com/tiles/images/symmetry_aperiodic_chair.png)). Thanks! Apparently *non-periodic* but not *aperiodic*. Definitely there exist infinite staircase cracks.

Comment: There is a question that we always ask our students when they learn induction (to show them that it's not always a matter of proving that the sum up to $n$ of something is some given function of $n$). The example is showing that you can tile a $2^n\times 2^n$ grid with one $1\times 1$ square removed by "L"-shaped tiles (3 tiles arranged in an L shape). The tilings this proof gives are essentially the chair tiling.

Comment: The chair tilings is the obvious example which is non-periodic. If you want a single aperiodic tile (that is, a tile which can tile the plane, but never periodically) then normally I would say you may be waiting a while - this is known as the *monotile* problem or *einstein* problem and remains open - http://math.stackexchange.com/a/533959/29059. However, L-polyominos do tile periodically so are not a solution.

Comment: @DanielRust: Thanks, Daniel, that's a wonderful MSE post!

Comment: "finite periodic series of steps up and down" -- should that be `up and right'?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher: Oh, you are right! Will correct...

Comment: The staircase in your chair tiling only happens because you chose a special point in the space of possible tilings. (These can be parameterized by quaternary sequences describing, for each level of deflation of the tiling, the position of the tile containing the origin in the next larger deflation...I think for aperiodic quaternary sequences you should avoid any infinite staircases.)

Comment: @DavidEppstein: Thank you, David, for that insight!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to not only avoid periodic monotonic staircases, but to avoid any infinite monotonic staircases whatsoever. This tiling of L-tetrominoes is periodic and features neither infinite monotonic staircases nor rectangles:

[image: faultless tiling]

I've highlighted copies of the fundamental region in different colours, so as to easily demonstrate the periodicity.

Comment: Beautiful, Adam! Thoroughly convincing.